# Determinant of a special matrix in characteristic $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, galois-representations, nonnoetherian

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p > 0$. Choose $p^i$ numbers of elements $c_1,\ldots,c_{p^i} \in K$ and consider the determinant $D$ of the following matrix$\colon$

\begin{pmatrix}\label{matrix} 
1 + c_1 - c_{p^i} & 1 + c_1 - c_{p^i-1} & 1 + c_1 - c_{p^i -2} & \ldots & 1 + c_1 - c_j & \ldots & 1 + c_1 - c_{2} & 1 \\
c_2 - c_1 & 1 + c_2 - c_{p^i} & 1 + c_2 - c_{p^i-1} & \ldots & 1 + c_2 - c_{j+1} & \ldots & 1 + c_2 - c_{3} & 1 \\
c_3 - c_2 & c_3 - c_1 & 1 + c_3 - c_{p^i} & \ldots & 1 + c_3 - c_{j+2} & \ldots & 1 + c_3 - c_4 & 1 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 1 \\
c_i - c_{i-1} & c_i - c_{i-2} & c_i - c_{i-3} & \ldots & 1 + c_{p^i+1-j} - c_{p^i} & \ldots & 1 + c_i - c_{i+1} & 1 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 1 \\
c_{p^i-1} - c_{p^i-2} & c_{p^i-1} - c_{p^i-3} & c_{p^i-1} - c_{p^i-4} & \ldots & c_{p^i-1} - c_{j -2} & \ldots & 1 + c_{p^i-1} - c_{p^i} & 1 \\
c_{p^i} - c_{p^i-1 }& c_{p^i} - c_{p^i-2} & c_{p^i} - c_{p^i-3} & \ldots & c_{p^i} - c_{j-1} & \ldots & c_{p^i} - c_{1} & 1
\end{pmatrix}

### Q. How can I prove that $D \not= 0$? Conjecturally, $D = 1$.

Comment: I do not understand the definition of the matrix: there is no $c_{p^i+1}$. Shoud not the $(p^i,p^i-1)$-th entry be $c^{p^i}-c_1$ ?

Comment: Dear Mark, you are perfectly right. Pierre

Comment: I think there is also something wrong with the next to last column, since there are no $c_{p^i+j-2}$ or $c_{p^i+j-1}$ for large $j$. I think that the last two entries of the next to last column should be $c_{p^i-1}-c_{p^i-j+2}$ and $c_{p^i}-c_{p^i-j+1}$, respectively. Is this correct?

Comment: Dear Mark, I guess $c_{p^i+j-2}$ and $c_{p^i+j-1}$ may be replaced with $c_{j-2}$ and $c_{j-1}$, respectively. They are periodic by $p^i$. Thanks.

Comment: The statements (i) $D\ne0$ for all choices of $K$ and $c_j$ (ii) $D=1$ for all choices of $K$ and $c_j$ (iii) Let $C_j$ be independent variables and let $F$ be the corresponding determinant in $\mathbb Z[C_1,...,C_{p^i}]$. Then $F$ is identically 1 are equivalent (in the sense that either all three are true or all three are false). Indeed, (iii)$\implies$(ii)$\implies$(i) are trivial. Assume (i). If $F$ was not identically 1, for all but finitely many choices of $p$ and all algebraically closed fields $K$ of characteristic $p$, the equation $F=0$ would have solutions in $K$, contradicting (i).